# How to change encoding from plain text to Unicode so that I can read special characters from a HTML?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

Below is my code :

```
<?php
// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
include('/Library/WebServer/Documents/simple_html_dom.php');  //this is the api for the simplehtmldom

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http:/www.google.hk');



// extract text from table
echo $html->find('td[align="top"]', 1)->innertext.'<br><hr>';

// extract text from HTML
echo $html->innertext;
?>
```

I am using the `simplephphtmldon` API. When I execute my **php** program in my local server instead I get so many unrecognized characters due to the fact that the plain text can't really encode them to show up like they supposed to. Can Someone tell me what i need to change to `inner text` in order to get all the characters to show up? PS i also did try `plaintext` without any luck. `textContent` seems broken to me. Perhaps i need to try a different element first (?). Thanks

Comment: Please post a sample input, the wrong output and the desired output.

Comment: try it now. i changed and instead of file it opens a webpage on the internet

Comment: **include('http://google.hk');** what are you trying to achieve with this ?

Comment: did you try running the code? I am trying to get some "special" characters to show up on my server. I want to read another site actually and then take some names from it (not google.hk but google.hk is a good example of it)

Comment: How can I run a code that uses `include('http://google.hk');` and a local file from your server/computer ??? either you update your question or I'll forced to vote close based on "**unclear what you're asking**"

Comment: i will update i am actually retarded and messed up with the code. editing now

Comment: i just want to know if it is possible to change the encoding from innertext to unicode so i can get all characters from all webpages instead of : ¼s§iªA°È

Comment: Your best bet is to get the encoding from the header and use that to convert it to utf-8 or other unicode encoding. Or you can try to use `mb_detect_encoding()` to detect the original encoding although arranging the encoding order can be difficult. innertext is not an encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo utf8_encode($html->innertext);
```

Or

```
echo utf8_decode($html->innertext);
```

It depends on the original encoding, so you may want to try both.

---

**Note:**
If you're seeing the output on a browser, make sure you set `Unicode` as text encoding or use this the following code at the top of you script.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: and sorry about the misunderstanding in the first place. Should have taken more careful look at my code before posting it online. May i ask another question? If you have a site that requires vpn can you establish a connection via php server?? Sorry for asking those noobish questions. Just started learning how to program

Comment: NP. To my understanding, no.